# Changes done from Spring 2 to Spring 3

Tags: java, spring

Recently while I was upgrading a project in spring 2.5.6 to spring 3.0.5, happened to know that some libraries aren't there anymore and some were renamed like spring-agent to spring-instrument...

Is there any site or a resource to refer to know these sort of changes done in migrating from spring 2 -3 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, for most purposes, the [Spring Upgrade Guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/upgrade/spring3/html/) should provide you with what you need. In particular, check section [2.5](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/upgrade/spring3/html/ch02s05.html) and [2.6](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/upgrade/spring3/html/ch02s06.html) on the new packaging model.

If you are looking for a class that appears to be no longer available, try searching for it with [FindJar](http://www.findjar.com/index.x). Some utility classes have been moved to another packages.